# Как сделать рандомный кликабельный фон через JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой, что мне требуется при каждом обновлении страницы получать каждый раз новый кликабельный фон, который перекидывал бы юзера на главную страницу сайта (при нажатии на сам фон, разумеется). Для этого я создал JavaScript-код, который помогает вывести эти самые изображения, но фоном их почему-то не делает. 
В общем, помогите сделать изображение фоном и присвоить ей ссылку на главную страницу...

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Error 404</title>
    </head>
    <body url="https://example.com">
        <div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/random_error.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

<!-- ниже приведён сам js-код -->

         function getRand(min, max){
      return Math.round(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
     }

     var images = new Array("img/404_1.png", "img/404_2.png");
     var lo = 0;
     var hi = images.length-1;
     var num = getRand(lo, hi);
     document.write("<img style='max-width: 1920px; height: auto; width: auto\9; border:1px solid #002244; ' src='"+images[num]+"'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function getRand(min, max){
      return Math.round(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
     }

     var images = new Array(
     "https://bugaga.ru/uploads/posts/2014-06/1402471536_prikoly-6.jpg", 
     "https://www.sunhome.ru/i/wallpapers/37/prikolnie-kartinki-oboi-na-rabochii-stol.orig.jpg"
     );
     var lo = 0;
     var hi = images.length-1;
     var num = getRand(lo, hi);
     console.log(num);
     var bg = document.getElementsByClassName("bg");
     bg[0].style.backgroundImage = "url("+images[num]+")";
```

```css
.bg {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Error 404</title>
    </head>
    <body url="https://example.com">
      <div class="bg"></div>
       <div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/random_error.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>

<!-- ниже приведён сам js-код -->
```